# Can I force matplotlib to block in a PyQt thread / process?

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a PyQt gui and I use a context menu action to execute a function. This function starts a matplotlib interaction where I use the mouse to draw on top of an image.

The problem is that when I call this function via the PyQt context menu action plt.show(block=True) does not block execution on that thread, and I am unable to interact with the matplotlib window.

More or less what happens in code looks like this. When I right click on an item in the PyQt widget I get a context menu:

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex, QtCore.QPoint)
def on_contextMenuClicked(widget, qtindex, pos):
  menu = QtGui.QMenu(widget)
  shortcut = QtGui.QKeySequence(0)
  action = menu.addAction('edit mask', edit_mask_func, shortcut)
  menu.exec_(widget.mapToGlobal(pos))
```

Then when I click the edit mask function it calls this function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def edit_mask_func():
    # code to start a matplotlib interaction
    plt.ion()
    fig = plt.figure(1)
    ax = plt.subplot(111)
    imgOver = np.zeros(img.shape, np.uint8) + 255
    ax.imshow(img, interpolation='nearest', alpha=1)
    ax.imshow(imgOver, interpolation='nearest', alpha=0.6)
    ax.grid(False)

    # This code handles the matplotlib interactive stuff
    # like setting up callbacks 
    # eg: fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', on_move)
    # and doing blit stuff. 
    pntr = Painter(fig, ax, imgOver)
    plt.title('Click on the image to draw. exit to finish')

    # THIS SHOULD BLOCK, BUT IT DOES NOT IF A CALLED BY 
    # QT INSTEAD OF THE MAIN THREAD
    plt.show(block=True)

    return pntr.img
```

If I call edit_mask_func from the main thread it works just fine. It seems that it is only a problem if I call the function via a PyQt thread.

Something that is telling is that if I try to force the program to block there by putting in a raw_input / input call I get this in stdout:

```
>>> input('hack to block... press enter when done')
QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running
hack to block... press enter when doneQCoreApplication::exec: The   event loop is already running
```

Ultimately, I need to integrate this interaction using a callback system, but I was hoping I could just do something quick and dirty for now. Is there any way to do this easily without writing callbacks?

I'm currently running with matplotlib_version 1.5.0 and PyQt4_version 4.10.4

Comment: There are a lot of things unclear about your code, but it looks like you are making GUI related calls from a secondary thread. PyQt (which matplotlib uses) is not thread safe and you will get segfaults if you continue down this path. If you need threading, make sure all GUI related code is executed in the main thread by emitting a signal from the secondary thread that connects to a slot in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that this is going to work, because "pyplot" is trying to start a second pyqt gui application with the embedded matplotlib canvas, once you call "plt.show()".

You should rather try embedding the matplotlib figure in your qt application like it is shown here:
 http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html